# Cordova windows application not working on another system

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, phonegap

Created an windows app using Visual studio cordova. Working fine when i install it on my system but not working when i try to install it in someone else's. I can't debug the app there because they don't have visual studio or anything. How do i check what is the issue

Comment: You getting any error?

Comment: Not on my system

Comment: Ok try to inspect using `chrome://inspect` on Chrome browser

Comment: you mean the www folder on localhost